# Editing a Post to get Publicity

Tags: discussion

When I create a post, and it does not get any, or little, response, I make a small edit, like adding a space where no one will notice it, to make it re-appear on the front page.

Is this okay?

Comment: Note: It's OK to do in the Sandbox from time to time, as long as you don't misuse it. Your challenge can drown quickly, and once you're on page 2, or far down on page 1 you're likely to get little feedback.

Comment: "Where no one will notice it". This reasoning is flawed, as anyone can view the edit history of the post and see exactly what you did.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### No, this is not OK.

The front page serves many purposes, but *get views for free* isn't one of them. You don't have to worry about making too many edits as long as they're intended to *improve* the post, but please don't edit them just to bump.

Assuming you mean questions, the proper way of drawing attention to them is to place a small bounty. These start at **50** rep and, if the challenge is interesting, usually pay for themselves.

There's no such facility for answers. Even the best ones can remain unnoticed. While that's unfortunate, I can't think of a way to fix this.

Comment: I often have the opposite problem - I avoid making small edits that fix something like grammar, etc, if the post is old enough. Maybe I should edit those things instead of avoiding it being pushed to the front page.

Comment: *Improving* is always fine. If I catch a typo in someone else's post, I'll fix that too.

Comment: Doesn't a bounty start at 100 rep? Is there a way to actually offer *50 rep*?

Comment: @SIGSEGV The minimum is 50. However, if you have already posted an answer to that question, the minimum is 100. You also have to double the amount every time you place a new bounty on the same question, up to the maximum of 500.