# Is it OK to keep editing my entries?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I answered something nice which gave me a daily cap. At first, my entry was around 350 bytes, and seemed pretty golfed. Today, my entry is only 182 bytes long (yeah Java!). To get there, I made around 20 edits (some with help, most without). Before submitting each edit, I think twice and try to golf more to the best I can. However sometimes after a few hours, sometimes after a few minutes I find something better and I edit again. Given that Java entries are long by default, this behavior is not rare. Golfing an entry with a specific algorithm can be ungolfable, but then another algorithm comes and is much more golfable, "requiring" an edit.

A side effect of this is that the question (of which I'm not the owner) stays in the front page, with my name next to it. Some might think [I edit to get publicity](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/editing-a-post-to-get-publicity), but no: all I'm really doing is golfing.

So is it acceptable to keep editing entries to golf more or improving the explanations? Or is there any reasonable limit?

Comment: TL;DR yes, it's ok

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

As long as you don't make trivial edits with the intention of boosting your own posts your are fine.  (trivial here means that it has no impact on the post, e.g. changing one word for a synonym).

As long as your edits improve your post, no matter how minor, they are welcome here.

I wouldn't worry about bumping anything to the front page unless you are doing a lot of edits across several questions.

Comment: From the answer in the question linked in the OP: `You don't have to worry about making too many edits as long as they're intended to improve the post, but please don't edit them just to bump.`

Comment: @StepHen Yep.  I agree with that completely, I'm just reiterating in an answer.